# How to return multiple if/else statements in kivy Label/python (Kivy label fail to return more than one if/else statement)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a simple quiz app in python and kivy using the if/else simple logic but I can't get what I want. The problem is that the kivy label is returning only one if/else block of my code. The rest if/else statments in the same function was ignored. I tried to debug it but I couldn't find out the problem. Please Help!! 
Bear with me if my question look stupid as I'm new to kivy and python.
Thanks in advance!!!!  The python part of the code is below:

```
def MyTest(self, *args, **kwargs):

    ids =[self.ids.my_label, self.ids.my_textinput]

        t = self.ids.my_textinput
        if t.text == "Hello":
            self.ids.my_label.text = "The text is\n Hello world"
        else:
            self.ids.my_label.text = "No answer\n wrong!!\n\n"

        if t.text == "is":     
            self.ids.my_label.text = "Correct!!!"
        else:
            self.ids.my_label.text = "Failed!!" 
    return
```

Comment: You can't return a statement or a block of code.  You can only return a value.  What value do you intend to return?

Comment: As it is, your code will have a syntax error due to the missing quote. Does what you posted match your actual code?

Comment: Also, in the code posted, the label will always contain the result of the final if/else block.

Comment: TigerhawT3- Yes, what I posted match the actual code.

Comment: TigerhawT3- Yes, what I posted match the actual code. @CurlyJoe  - Yes, the label always contain the result of the final if/else block. How can I put the code in a good order to get the desired result? Help Please. A big thanks to you all!!

Comment: What do you want the label to contain if the text is neither `"Hello"` nor `"is"`?

Comment: Thanks @Rouven B for the edit. Curly Joe answer is a big help to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something along the lines of

```
    t = self.ids.my_textinput  ## can't tell what this does
    if t.text == "Hello":
        self.ids.my_label.text = "The text is\n Hello world"
    elif t.text == "is":     
        self.ids.my_label.text = "Correct!!!"
    else:
        self.ids.my_label.text = "Whatever you want if every compare failed"
```

Comment: Thanks a million @Curly Joe. Your answer gave me an idea of how to restructure the code. Thanks again!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a bunch of if/elif, use a dictionary http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm

```
t_dict= {"Hello":"The text is\n Hello world",
         "is":"Correct!!!"}
t = self.ids.my_textinput
if t.text in t_dict:
    self.ids.my_label.text = t_dict[t.text]
else:
    self.ids.my_label.text = "Whatever you want if every compare failed"
```

Comment: You're still not avoiding `if/else` in your code. You probably meant `t_dict.get(t.text, 'Default value')`.