# how to use" if ,else if, else "condition in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

How can I create a conditional text label in kivy 
for example if x=1 text='Hi' if x=2 text='Hello' if x=1 text='helloword'

```
Label:
    text:'hi' if root.x=='1''hello' elseif root.x=='1' else 'helloworls'
```

something like this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return multiple if/else statements in kivy Label/python (Kivy label fail to return more than one if/else statement)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173490/how-to-return-multiple-if-else-statements-in-kivy-label-python-kivy-label-fail)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part after `text:` is Python syntax (not kivy specific):
`text:'hi' if root.x=='1' else 'hello' if root.x=='2' else 'helloworls'`